# Receiving Socket.IO message 2 times

Tags: javascript, socket.io

On a button click, I emit a message with socket.io:

```
$("#view-button").click(function () {
    console.log("button clicked");
    var textInfo = {
        msg: $("#message-field").val(),
        date: $("#date-field").val()
    }  
    socket.emit("text request", textInfo);
});
```

In my index.js file, it receives it:

```
socket.on("text request", function(textInfo) {
    var textData;
    if (date >= 6) {
        textData = "beginning";
    else {
        textData = "end";
    }
    socket.emit("text", textData);
}
```

Then I receive the "text" socket message:

```
socket.on("text", function(textData) {
    console.log(textData);
    console.log("text data received");
});
```

However, I am receiving the "text" socket message twice. I know this as "text data received" is being printed to the console twice. I checked the functions where the request is being emitted and the function where the text request is received and each of them only trigger once. How come I am seeing 2 "text data received" messages in the console but only one "text" socket message is being emitted?

Comment: remove space from your event names, as in make it text_request and text.

Answer (score 0):

`emit` will send to all the clients including sender.

`broadcast.emit` will send the message to all the other clients except the newly created connection

So in your case you are using emit, at both the point thus making the message to receive 2 times.

Comment: If I change either of them to socket.broadcast.emit, the message does not emit

Comment: I've updated my original post with the completed code

Comment: At both the end you are emitting the value, when you are receiving the event at backend then you need to emit the data not while sending the data from frontend.